# Extension methods to save and load form size, position, and state

Tags: c#, winforms, windows, extension-methods

I wrote these extension methods to provide a generic/re-usable method for saving a form's size, position, and window state. What I would primarily like to know is if there is a better way to handle storing the `WindowState` property. I would also like to know if there are any bugs I might have overlooked, unnecessary code, or ways to make it more readable.

```
public static void SaveFormSizeAndLocation( this Form form )
{
    try 
    {
        using( RegistryKey key = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.CreateSubKey(form.Name) )
        {
            if( key != null )
            {
                if( form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal )
                {
                    key.SetValue("Left",form.Left);
                    key.SetValue("Top",form.Top);
                    key.SetValue("Width",form.Width);
                    key.SetValue("Height",form.Height);
                }
                if( form.ShowInTaskbar )
                {
                    string windowState = Enum.GetName(typeof(FormWindowState),form.WindowState);
                    key.SetValue("WindowState",form.WindowState);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        // Party on, Garth!
    }
}
public static void LoadFormSizeAndLocation( this Form form )
{
    try
    {
        using( RegistryKey key = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.OpenSubKey(form.Name) )
        {
            if( key != null )
            {
                form.Left = (int)key.GetValue("Left",form.Left);
                form.Top = (int)key.GetValue("Top",form.Top);
                form.Width = (int)key.GetValue("Width",form.Width);
                form.Height = (int)key.GetValue("Height",form.Height);
                // Move window into visible screen bounds if outside screen bounds (prevent off-screen hidden windows)
                Rectangle screenRect = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;
                if( form.Left < screenRect.Left )
                    form.Left = screenRect.Left;
                if( form.Top < screenRect.Top )
                    form.Top = screenRect.Top;
                if( form.Right > screenRect.Right )
                    form.Left = screenRect.Right - form.Width;
                if( form.Bottom > screenRect.Bottom )
                    form.Top = screenRect.Bottom - form.Height;
                if( form.ShowInTaskbar )
                {
                    string windowState = Enum.GetName(typeof(FormWindowState),form.WindowState);
                    windowState = key.GetValue("WindowState",windowState).ToString();
                    form.WindowState = (FormWindowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(FormWindowState),windowState);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Party on, Wayne!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Unnecessary code

The `windowState` variable isn't used in the `SaveFormSizeAndLocation` method. And I believe you don't need such variable at all, because `form.WindowState.ToString()` returns exactly the same string.

---

### Suggestions

**The `SaveFormSizeAndLocation` method.**
You check the `key` for `null` value, and if it is `null` nothing happens. Maybe it makes sense to omit that check and to handle (or raise) the exception in order to inform user or to save the reason in the application log.

**The `LoadFormSizeAndLocation` method.**
You can reduce nesting by inverting the condition:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.OpenSubKey(form.Name))
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    form.Left = (int)key.GetValue("Left",form.Left);
    form.Top = (int)key.GetValue("Top",form.Top);
    ...
}
```

---

### Naming

I believe that extension methods for the `Form` class shouldn't contain the word 'Form' in their names. Consider to shorten names: `SaveSizeAndLocation` and `LoadSizeAndLocation`.

---

### Styling

It looks unnatural for me:

- Spaces after `(` and before `)`. I'd prefer to insert spaces before the `(` in operators:

  ```
  if (x != y)
  ```

  and to omit spaces in method declarations and calls:

  ```
  someMethod(int a, float b, string c);
  someMethod(a, b, c);
  ```
- No spaces between method arguments. I'd prefer to add a space after each comma:

  ```
  SomeMethod(firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg);
  ```

  This should improve readability.
  Personally, I cannot easily distinguish between

  ```
  SomeMethod(abc,def,ghi); // 3 arguments
  ```

  and

  ```
  SomeMethod(abc.def.ghi); // 1 argument
  ```